# Can I reach all label in a label[][] with mouselistener / mouseadapter?

Tags: java, swing, label, mouselistener

I have a label[][] and all label in this have mouseadapter, when any mouselistener fired I want to reach all label. All label have an Icon. If I click in one all label should change their icon.

example from my code:

```
for(int x = 1; x < 11; x++){
        for(int y = 1; y < 11; y++){
            label[x][y].setIcon(korok[randomGenerator.nextInt(6)]);
            label[x][y].addMouseListener(new LabelMouseListener(x, y));}}
        }
    }

public class LabelMouseListener extends MouseAdapter{
private final int x, y;

public LabelMouseListener() {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                    int egyklik[] = new int[3];

                    if(egyklik[0] == 0){
                        egyklik[0] = 1; egyklik[1] = x; egyklik[2] = y;
                    }
                    else if(egyklik[0] == 1){
                        //JLabel l = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                        // it's wrong code, i would like something what will do this,
                        //if i do the Override in the other(JFrame) class, it can
                        //reach labels, but can't use x and y

                        //label[x][y].setIcon(label[egyklik[1]][egyklik[2]].getIcon());
                        //label[egyklik[1]][egyklik[2]].setIcon(label[x][y].getIcon());
                    }
                }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can reach to all labels.

Why you start from `index 1.` see in your for loop(`int x = 1 and int y = 1`).

I think x and y start with `index 0`.

`x < 11; and y< 11;` need to change to `x < 10;and y < 10;` respectivly.

In your mouseClicked() method do like this.

```
JLabel l = null;
if(e.getSource() instanceof JLabel){
     l = (JLabel) e.getSource();

}
```

Comment: I have a frame the x, y = 0 , 11 is this, but I think it's not important. Otherwise I found a solution (although I don't know it is totally regular). Anyway Thanks, I used your example too. If anyone needs the working code just ask.